# Returning array made with calloc to main

Tags: c

So I have a problem:

My program has to find the most common element in an array. We have to make this array with `calloc`. My code is working but I am asked to move part of my code to a function in which I have to create an array and enter numbers.

```
int main() {
    int n, i, dazn;
    int *A;
    dazn = 0;
    printf("Iveskite naturalu skaiciu: \n");// enter how many elements in an array we will have
    scanf("%d", &n);
    A = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int)); // Starting from here...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Iveskite skaiciu \n"); 
        scanf("%d", &A[i]); // 
    }
    ... // and ending here have to be in a function
    ... // sorting and finding the most common element
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Make a function `int *myfunc(int n)`, copy the relevant stuff, and `return A;`. But as you do nothing with `A`, it is irrelevant!

Comment: So like that? It doesn't work 
https://gyazo.com/d4331f664201da93300f66390cae36c0

I have other functions where I use array A

Comment: @Valentinno7: try using English names for functions and variables, this is both more consistent with the language keywords and much easier to read for people across the world.

Comment: In your link's `main`, you need `A = sukurimas(n);` and you also need function prototypes.

Comment: Thank you, it finally worked! 
I will try to use English words in a future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As instructed, move the code to a separate function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *allocate_and_read_array(int size) {
    int *A = (int*)calloc(size, sizeof(int));
    if (A != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            printf("Iveskite skaiciu \n"); 
            if (scanf("%d", &A[i]) != 1) {
                printf("Missing values\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return A;
}

int main(void) {
    int n, i, dazn;
    int *A;
    dazn = 0;
    printf("Iveskite naturalu skaiciu: \n");// enter how many elements in an array we will have
    scanf("%d", &n);
    A = allocate_and_read_array(n);

    ... // sort the array
    ... // find the most common element

    free(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return NULL`? you need to return A

Comment: @cpatricio: absolutely! Thanks